# Contradictions on restrictions for objects outside of lifetime

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, lifetime

[[basic.life]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#7) says this about outside of lifetime objects:

> Similarly, before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated
> [...]
> The program has undefined behavior if:
>
> - the glvalue is used to access the object, or
>
> [...]

It also references [[class.cdtor]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.cdtor):

> [...] For an object under construction or destruction, see [class.cdtor]. [...]

Where, in the 1 clause it is stated:

> For an object with a non-trivial constructor, referring to any non-static member or base class of the object before the constructor begins execution results in undefined behavior. For an object with a non-trivial destructor, referring to any non-static member or base class of the object after the destructor finishes execution results in undefined behavior.

"before the constructor begins execution" here means the objects is not under construction yet, which also means it's lifetime has not started.

So, according to this, as long as an object has a trivial constructor/destructor, its ok to access it's members outside of it's lifetime.

But isn't that a contradiction to what is given in [[basic.life]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life)? How does this rules work in relation to each other exactly?

Comment: My immediate reaction is just because one clause does not cover one particular situation involving undefined behavior doesn't mean that some other clause won't.

Comment: "referring to any non-static member" != "accessing any non-static member": https://godbolt.org/z/MPKEj49jr

Comment: Your interpretation is backward.   Both clauses list sets of circumstances that result in undefined behaviour.    A situation listed within the set circumstances listed by one clause, but not by the other clause, doesn't cancel out undefined behaviour.   In set theory, the first clause lists a set of circumstances A, the second lists a set of circumstances B, so any situation that is in either A or B has undefined behaviour.  The only situations that do not have undefined behaviour are NOT in set A and ALSO NOT in set B

Comment: You should not eat rocks. You should also not eat toxic substances. Doesn't imply you should eat non-toxic rocks.

Comment: @PasserBy: The C and C++ Standards use the same terminology to describe (1) actions which would *generally* invoke UB, but whose behavior in some particular cases should recognized as defined by some other parts of the Standard, and (2) actions which should be characterized as invoking UB even if other parts of the Standard would otherwise define theri behavior.  If 99.9% of rocks were toxic, the two statements together should not be viewed as implying anything in particular about the 0.1% of rocks that happen to be non-toxic.

Comment: I always said lifetime was a complete and utter mess, thank you for bringing it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A glvalue of class type cannot be used to perform an access, meaning a read or write. See [Note 10 in [basic.lval]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#note-10). You can access members of class objects, but such an access wouldn't be through a glvalue of class type directly. You would have to use the member access notation or an operation that implicitly accesses members (e.g. an implicitly defined copy constructor).

As such, [basic.life]/7.1 applies to scalar types. It is UB to access them outside their lifetime.

And [class.cdtor]/1 states that when a class type has a nontrivial constructor, you cannot even **refer** to its non-static data members before the constructor begins execution—meaning, even if you do not attempt to **access** those members, but merely evaluate an expression that names one (e.g., to form a pointer or reference to it), your program has UB. Same goes if the class type has a nontrivial destructor and you attempt to refer to one of its non-static data members after the destructor completes.

There is no contradiction.

For trivial class types to which [class.cdtor]/1 does not apply, you *may* refer to their members before construction begins or after destruction finishes, but if they are of scalar type, you still may not access them under [basic.life]/7.1.